# How to not duplicate code for printing tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree, code-duplication

I have a function that prints tree nodes from left to right.

```
void PrintTree()
{
...
Print(curentNode);
...
}
```

But now I want to add a function that prints nodes that meet some condition.
For example, print only such nodes, strings of which start with a given string. So it would look like

```
void PrintTreeByCondition(string a)
{
...
if(IsPrefix(a,curentNode->stringVar))
      Print(curentNode);
...
}
```

But then I have two functions with the same code, with the difference in one line. How would I avoid code duplication here?

UPD: Traverse code:

```
void BinTree::TraverseTree()
{
    std::stack<TreeNode*> s;
    s.push(root);
    TreeNode* curentNode = s.top();
    while (curentNode != nullptr|| s.empty() == false)
    {
        while (curentNode != nullptr)
        {
            s.push(curentNode);
            curentNode = curentNode->GetLeft();
        }

        curentNode = s.top();
        s.pop();

        // do stuff

        curentNode = curentNode->GetRight();
    }
}
```

Comment: *How to not duplicate code for printing tree* -- How about code that traverses the tree in general, and call a function provided by the user when a node is visited?  That would be a much better, generic approach.  What if you want to do something to a visited node other than print it?  Let's see the traversal code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I was thinking about something like this and thought to use a pointer to a function, something like ```void TraverseTree(void (*f)(const CTreeNode*))``` . But after that I could not figure out how to implement the second behavior with it.

Comment: Ok, you are on the right track.  Post the code that traverses the tree (not the Print function, just the traversal code).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie added. Looking at the answer provided by Dietmar Kühl I understand that I need to add something like iterators to my tree. I can do this only by adding a pointer to the node's parent in the node class, right?

Comment: UPD: got it, my iterators can just store stack that represent way to the root as I do in my traverse

Comment: You could do something like this: `template <typename fn> void traverse( node *p, fn func) { if ( p ) {traverse(p->left, fn); fn(p); traverse(p->right, fn); }}`, where `fn` is the pointer to a function, a function object, lambda, etc.  That would be in-order traversal.

Comment: But that wouldn't allow my lambda function to have other parameters, right? Like in my PrintTreeByCondition I have ```string a```. How would I implement something like this with the lambda function? The only way I can think of is some global/static variable that would represent ```string a```, which isn't the best solution in my opinion

Comment: Use an object that has `operator()` overloaded.

Comment: @IvanIvan: The function object you'd provide would take arguments a `traverse()` function would pass to it for every node. For example, if your tree nodes contain a `T` objects as their value, the function would probably take a `T const&` as parameter. Depending on whether the `traverse()` function is a function template are not it would take its visitor function either as template parameter with a [n implicate] concept of being callable with `T const&`. If it isn't a template it would probably take a `std::function<void(T const&)>` as parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C++ ways is to create an iterator for the traversal and use that for printing as well as filtering or other uses. Traversing a tree can probably be done in a bidirectional fashion which would allow plenty of algorithms to become accessible for the tree, too. In fact, the ordered associative containers (e.g., `std::map`, `std::set`) are normally implemented as [balanced] binary trees and their iterators do an in-order traversal.

The details of iteration do depend on the tree representation. The associative containers are normally implemented with a parent pointer. If there is no such pointer each iterator will need to maintain suitable space to represent the path back to the root (the standard library containers can't do that because they have requirements for iterator stability which prevents that). The slightly odd thing about traversal using iterators is that doesn't lend itself directly to an implementation using recursion. In return, control over the iteration is given to the user of the iterators.

Answer (score 2):

Given your function, another approach would be to make the `TraverseTree` function take a function to invoke once a node is discovered:

```
template <typename fn>
void BinTree::TraverseTree(fn func)
{
    std::stack<TreeNode*> s;
    s.push(root);
    TreeNode* curentNode = s.top();
    while (curentNode != nullptr|| s.empty() == false)
    {
        while (curentNode != nullptr)
        {
            s.push(curentNode);
            curentNode = curentNode->GetLeft();
        }
        curentNode = s.top();
        s.pop();
        func(currentNode);  // call custom function
        curentNode = curentNode->GetRight();
    }
}
```

Then `Print` would simply be:

```
void Print(Node *n)
{
   std::cout << n->data << "\n"; // assuming there is a "data" member
}
```

And the final call would be:

```
BinTree b;
//...
b.TraverseTree(&Print);
```

---

If you have other information to print, pass a function object (a class that has `operator()` overloaded), and within the object is everything necessary to do the work intended (usually represented as class members):

For example:

```
struct MyPrint
{
    std::string some_value;

    MyPrint(std::string s) : some_value(s) {}

    void operator() (Node *n) 
    { 
       std::cout << some_value << " -- " << n->data << "\n"; 
    }
};
```

Then call it like this:

```
BinTree b;
//...
MyPrint m("Testing testing");
b.TraverseTree(m);
```